# How to check that the month is equal to December using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

So I'm very new to jQuery/Javascript and was just trying to make snow appear during the month of December to have a play with dates so I can get used to them for other things.

I can't work out why this doesn't work. Is it the mix of jQuery/Javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    n = d.getMonth();

    if (n == 11) {
       $.fn.snow();
    }
});
```

This however does work but doesn't have the date function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.snow();
});
```

Comment: May be because you are getting **`n as 10`** for current November month. Try to hard code `n` as `11` and test it again.

Comment: Your code is right.   Make sure you system time is `December`..  Here is jsfiddle to prove it is working http://jsfiddle.net/9BzC3/

Comment: It's worth mentioning that .getMonth() results in 0 for January to 11 for December. So it's one month off compared to the "regular counting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript `date.getMonth()` is numbered from `0` to `11` and not `1` to `12` so in order to make your code work in *november* you have to check `10` and not `11` (or add 1 to your variable `n`).

By the way, you probably missed the `var` keyword before your `n` variable.

Comment: Typo... just corrected it. (or maybe I counted movember as the 13th month ;))

Comment: I can't for another 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
            var d = new Date();
            n = d.getMonth() + 1;
```

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date,

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work only in `December only` if you want to check then you have to pass any `date` of `December month` like,

```
var d = new Date("12 Dec 2013");
n = d.getMonth(); // will alert 11 now
```

**Full Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date("12 Dec 2013");
    n = d.getMonth();

    if (n == 11) {
       $.fn.snow();
    }
});
```